# How to set rowspan for a div in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to set rowspan for a div to combine rows in bootstrap. Please note that I am trying to achieve this without creating extra div and nesting a divs which are the usual methods.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color: pink;">A</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color: pink;">B</div>
        <div  class="col-sm-2" style="background-color: yellow;" >
        <hr/>  #Rowspan for this div#
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color: green;">C</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color: green;">D</div>
     </div>
```

Output:
[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Comment: you don't have a rowspan here you have a <hr> ... what exactly do you want?

Comment: Not for <hr/> I want rowspan for the div that contains <hr/>

Comment: You can't achieve this without restructuring the divs.